# integer divison with negative remainder

Tags: math, integer, modulo

I'm trying to find a name for mathematical division operation which can produce negative reminder.

Examples of expected:

`5 %? 2 = 2*2 + 1
11 %? 3 = 4*3 - 1`

module of reminder should be as small as possible.

Does someone knew the name of such operation?

Comment: I believe the question is not well-defined; since `11 % 3 = 4*3 - 1` and also `11 % 3 = 5*3 - 4`, the remainder can made arbitrarily small by increasing one of the factors. Please clarify the question.

Comment: abs(reminder) should be as small as possible. This rule out `5*3 - 4`.

Comment: Both `3*2-1` and `2*2 + 1` are equally good.

Comment: See [Residue Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Residue_systems). I don't know of any standard name but when I have needed to explain it I have called it the *minimum absolute value residue system*.

Comment: @James. It appears that the standard Least Residue System contains the smallest natural numbers (no negative numbers). I like the name of your  _minimum absolute value residue system._ George just needs to check his result. If its greater than half the divisor, subtract the divisor.

Comment: `least absolute remainder` at Wiki remainder page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder

Answer (score 0):

Computer language remainder functions return a positive remainder. What you need is simple. In your second example you want is a remainder of -1.

```
11 %? 3 = 4*3 - 1
```

But what you get is a remainder of 2.

```
11 %? 3 = 3*3 + 2
```

As I said in the comments, check the remainder 2 against half the divisor 3/2 = 1.5. Since the remainder is greater than half the divisor, subtract the divisor:

```
2 - 3 = -1
```

Yes, you will have to store a real number for half the divisor.